# Pass data from child click to parent event callback in CanJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canjs, canjs-control

In CanJS controller, I am using click event inside another click handler. How can I pass some data to parent handler from child handler

```
someController=can.Control({
    init:function(element,options){
    //  some code
    },
    '.someButtonSelector click':function(el,ev)
    {
        console.log(this.options.someData) //Returns array of objects
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('#someFormButton').click(function()
        {
            var formData=can.deparam($('someFormSelector').serialize());
            //Want to add formObject in this.options.someData array

        })
    },      
})
```

I want to put formData into this.options. here `this` represents object of `someController` so I cannot use it directly inside the `someFormButton` click event.

Also want to know if I am following the right approach? Scenario is on clicking the `someButtonSelector` a form appears. I want to put the formData into current options object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is adding a click handler within another handler what you really want to do? Your code would mean that a new click handler will be added to `#someFormButton` *every* time someone clicks on `.someButtonSelector`. If `#someFormButton` is also within the Controls element I think what you'd like to do (adding the serialized data to `this.options.formData` when clicking `#someFormButton`) should look something like this:

```
var someController = can.Control({
    init:function(element,options){
    //  some code
    },

    '.someButtonSelector click':function(el,ev)
    {
        console.log(this.options.someData) //Returns array of objects
        ev.preventDefault();
    },  

    '#someFormButton click': function(el, ev) {
        var formData = can.deparam($('someFormSelector').serialize());
        this.options.formData.push(formData);
    }    
})
```